# Pool skimmer drain suction

Tags: drain, pool, pump

I have 15k gallon pool with a 1.5hp pump,  1 skimmer and 1 drain. I have a Float valve assembly over the skimmer. If the skimmer is fully open does that mean there is no suction in the drain? I don't want suction in the drain. How does this work?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a picture of a pool pump that I've worked on:

[image: Picture of pump]

See the gray valve right before the pump/basket on the left?  That's a three-way valve.  It can be turned a couple of different directions in order to adjust the flow of the water.  If you turn it one way, it will pull entirely from the drain, and if you turn it the other way, it will pull entirely from the skimmers.  In that picture, it's positioned halfway in between -- 50% drain, 50% skimmers.

If you want to pull from the drain only, you're going to have to move the three-way valve that's positioned in front of your pump.  If you have a spa, it will have two three-way valves.  You'll have to figure out how it works by messing with them.  If the pump starts making bad noises, it's either pulling in air or you've turned the valve in such a way that it blocks the pump's inlet, which is something that you don't want to do.  If it happens, turn the valve 90 degrees in either direction to open up the pipe going to the pump.

Comment: Oops... sorry, Niall. :)  I've been using imgur.com pretty well the past few weeks but forgot about it. :(

Comment: You have a nice setup. We recently bought the house and unfortunately we do not have a nice setup and equipment  like yours. I added an image to of our setup in my question above. Is the blue handle at the bottom of the photo what control the suction between skimmer and drain. Can you tell which one is the drain pipe.

Comment: That's a gate valve.  It will shut that specific pipe off, which is presumably the skimmer(s).  You'll probably have to turn it quite a bit, though -- maybe 20 times before it will completely block the skimmers off.  Unfortunately gate valves aren't very trustworthy in the long run, so I'd expect the skimmers to be 95% blocked off, not 100%.

Comment: Thanks. I want to actually turn of the drain suction to avoid any suction entrapment. Just a safety thing. I'm assuming i just need to turn the knob either way and see which way shuts off the drain. I would assume the lower pipe is the drain, otherwise if the lower pipe is for the skimmer then the turning the knob will only block/unblock the skimmer and drain will always be open. Do i have this right.

Comment: As you'll see in your pictures, you have two pipes coming out of the concrete.  There's about a 99.9% chance that one is coming from the drain and one from the skimmer... and there's about a good chance that the gate valve is on the skimmer pipe.  In order to drain the pool, you have to stop the pump from sucking in air from the skimmers, which is why it's most likely the case that the gate valve is for them, not the drain.  If it is indeed the skimmer, you'll want to keep it open, as closing it would force the pump to pull from the drain exclusively.  You could try it, but I suspect this is..

Comment: what will happen.  Unfortunately, if it's the case that the gate valve shuts off the skimmer and not the drain, you'll have to start looking for other options.  The cheapest option would definitely be to simply change the pipes near the pump, installing either a ball valve on the drain's pipe or a three-way valve where all three of the pipes come together.  Another option is to get a drain that prevents suction entrapment, or install a second drain (which is often done in hot tubs.)

Comment: So based on your explanation, if the gate valve is open all the way, we have 50% suction from skimmer and 50% from drain. and if it's closed then we have 100% suction from drain. To fix this with a 3 way valve, should i cut the pipe that's connected to the pump, raise/hook it up to the middle between the skimmer and drain pipe connected with a 3 way valve.

Comment: 1) That is probably the case, but I can't say for certain.  You should test it to see what it does.  2) If I'm correct about that, though, we can talk about fixing the problem.  Unfortunately the person that installed this didn't really plan ahead in terms of making it easy to modify the system, but it's fixable.  I'd cut the Tee where all three come together and then put a coupling on both the pump's inlet pipe and the drain's pipe, with a roughly 2.5"-long piece of 2-2.5" PVC (you'll have to figure out the diameter and exact length,) which would feed into a three-way valve.

Comment: Probably best to get rid of the gate valve as well, so I'd cut it right below the gate valve , and then bring a new pipe up just like they did (the raised section might be there for a reason -- is the pump below the water level of the pool?) and then back down, into the new three-way valve.

Comment: Note: Make sure when you cut the Tee out that you cut as little as possible... otherwise you might not have enough space to put the coupling right next to the elbow leading to the pump.  (At which point you'd have to replace the elbow as well.)  DRY FIT EVERYTHING FIRST, then apply primer to the portions of pipe that are to be glued, and THEN glue.  Don't try to wing it and just start gluing stuff in as soon as you cut it.  Also, make sure the water level is below the pump before you start cutting -- if it's not, backwash water to the street with a hose.

Comment: Also, glue the upside down "U" section last.  If you glue it in before you do the three-way valve, it might be impossible to get the three-way valve in.  There's not much play in the pipes since they're embedded in concrete.

Comment: I lost you on the last comment "the upside down u". Are you suggesting the 3 way valve goes between the pump elbow and drain pipe. If yes, then i'm assuming the skimmer pipe will go up then back down directly to the 3 way pipe without connecting with the drain pipe. It will connect directly with the 3 way valve. The pump is above water water level. Wouldn't the setup be easier if we cut the pump elbow, extend it to the front then raise it up to meet the middle between the drain and the skimmer pipes and that's where the 3 way valve can go.

Comment: You can rig it up however you want to; you just need to get all three pipes to merge in the same location, feeding into a three-way valve.  (Any orientation of the three-way valve is fine.  Pump doesn't necessarily have to be connected to the middle of the three-way valve.)  Keep in mind that you can't unglue a join, and you don't really have room for error here -- there's not much pipe to work with -- you can't keep cutting your mistakes out over and over again.  You've only got one or two tries to get it right before you end up making the situation worse, so be careful and think ahead.

Comment: Hey Michael, I tried to turn the gate valve both ways, neither closed suction on the skimmer. Does this mean that the pipe with the gate valve is to for the drain.

Comment: Did you turn it several times?  We're not talking about a two or three turn sorta deal.  Going to have to turn it maybe a dozen times.  I wouldn't make any assumptions, as it's possible the gate valve has been ruined by the chlorinated water.  I sorta doubt that thing was designed to be installed in a pool.   Rather than assume it is successfully turning the drain off, I'd probably put a dozen popcorn kernels or something like that into the drain and then turn the pump on with the valve turned all the way to the right.  If no kernels show up in the basket, the drain is off.